AWS: Can't connect my Docker container hosted in EC2 to my RDS
I'm trying to deploy a university project using Docker Compose and EC2. The purpose to achieve is to have an auto scaling group with EC2 starting my application using docker compose and linked to an RDS with a MySQL engine. To achieve this, I intend to configure an EC2 instance so that it is only necessary to start the containers with docker compose up, and replicate that AMI to take it as a starting point for the instances of the auto scaling group. I am currently configuring this initial instance.
To do this, I first created a docker-compose.yml file with two containers: one for the backend (coded in Java Spring Boot) and another for the frontend (coded in Vuejs). In the backend service I included the environment variables with host, user and password of the RDS, whose values I have exposed in my application.properties file using the nomenclature ${ENV_VALUE}.
That said, when I raise the containers in my EC2 I get connection errors that say the following:
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure.
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Some details to keep in mind are:

EC2 and RDS are located in the same VPC.

RDS is not publicly accessible (I tried changing it to be publicly accessible and initiating a connection from my Windows machine, but that didn't work either)

The EC2 is not connected to the RDS (I understand that to connect the container itself it is not necessary that the EC2 itself is connected to the RDS).


I also tried adding a rule to the RDS security group that would allow SQL traffic but my EC2 would get stuck when running containers.
That said, I don't know exactly where the connection error may be coming from, if any more data is needed to troubleshoot the problem I can provide it.

Does this answer your question? com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I should have mentioned that I'm using Spring Boot, so the database connection is established automatically. I configured the application.properties database params with the docker compose env variables. It seemed to be a routing config issue as @Chris said. I was able to connect from my EC2, but when I ran docker compose up, the EC2 got blocked, so now I guess the trouble is a hardware issue, as CPU usage is constantly very high.

This is most likely a routing configuration issue. With AWS when I'm working from scratch, I almost always start out with the simplest problem. In your case, I would try accessing the RDS instance from an EC2 host you SSH into. To do that, there are a few things you will need to do.

First, I would make sure the RDS port is configured correctly.
Then, make sure you make a note of the subnets that the database is in (most likely private subnets).
Next, make sure the security group attached to your instance has port 22 open (for SSH if you want to connect from your windows computer).
Open up the security group of your RDS database to allow inbound access from the EC2 instance.
Install a basic DB client on the instance and make sure you can connect to your RDS instance.
Once you've verified the connection, then restart the process from within the Docker instance and it should be fixed
In my experience, a connection timeout is typically from either a security group misconfiguration (not opening it up enough), or a routing issue so you will want to make sure that the subnets can talk to each other through the routing tables.

You may also want to check the network ACL's but those are defaulted to allow all traffic so that shouldn't be too much of an issue in this case.

I have checked that the security group of the VPC in which the RDS is located has port 3306 open. I opened it for my own IP and tried to connect using MySQL Workbench, which resulted in error. Then I tried to open all incoming traffic on port 3306 of the same security group (as a temporary test) and tried to connect using a mysql container from EC2 itself, which also failed. I have also checked the subnets the database is on. As I am using the default VPC, it is on the three default subnets.
I still can't find the solution, maybe I start over again by systematically following these steps.
